# Free jqGrid 4.8.0 - Set Locale automatically base on user environment

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Is there a way I can set the user locale automatically based on the user windows/linux OS settings?

Today I need to explicitly include the relevant js.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways **to detect** the user locale automatically, but I don't know any perfect solution. All depends on your exact requirements. For example one can use `navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage`. You will get the string like `"en-US"` for example. [The old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) for [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/) demonstrates the usage of `navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage`.

The user can still have another language preferences in the settings of web browser:

[image]

and so the web browser will include `Accept-Language` header in HTTP requests to the server:

```
Accept-Language: de,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2
```

The settings can be different in different web browsers which the user uses

[image]

So I recommend you to provides the user some possibility (an `<select>` element for example) to make the choice manually.

After detection of the language you need verify whether the corresponding language is already loaded. You can test whether the corresponding language property already defined in `$.jgrid.locales` (`if ($.jgrid.locales[locale] !== undefined)`). If it's not defined then you have to load the corresponding JavaScript file dynamically. You can test additionally the value of `$.jgrid.defaults.locale`. The value will be set in every locale file. So `$.jgrid.defaults.locale` gives you information about the last loaded locale file and about the default locale of free jqGrid. One can still specify `locale` explicitly during creating the grid. See [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Support-of-multiple-locales-on-the-same-page) for some additional information.